# create named-pipe in java

Tags: c#, java, ipc, named-pipes

I found this [Example](http://v01ver-howto.blogspot.co.at/2010/04/howto-use-named-pipes-to-communicate.html)

but I want it the other way around, I want to create a named-pipe with java and the C# (or any other) application connects to this pipe. Is this possible at all? and if yes, how?

Thanks
florian

Comment: If you read the code you see it's kind of like writing to a file (which named pipes kid of is).
You swap the read from java to write and vice versa, and thats it.

Comment: yes but if I create a file in java, how can I access it with NamedPipeClientStream in .net?

Comment: using the same filename for each applications and opening and closing the file for every call; you can't use NamedPipeClientStream but a FileStream class. all keeping in mind that if one application is writing, the other can't open the file and viceversa

Answer (score 0):

The creation of a named pipe in java is OS dependent, you need to create it with the command Runtime.getRuntime().exec: you can't do like in .net; here is an example on how to do it in unix http://code.google.com/p/jdds/source/browse/trunk/JDDS/src/rtjdds/rtps/transport/NamedPipe.java?spec=svn7&r=7.

In other way you can create the pipe in the .net application and then swap the code in the example you provided.

Comment: Thanks! the thing is this should run on unix and windows, and so on unix I won't have any .net applications

Comment: Can't you use sockets? Is more os flexible.

Comment: The link to source code mentioned above (for Linux pipe creation via an exec() call) has now changed: See https://github.com/sioutisc/jdds/blob/master/JDDS/src/rtjdds/rtps/transport/NamedPipe.java instead.